# Sorting a vector of objects using a compare function

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am trying to follow a link where a someone is trying to simplify the C++ sort reference http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/4817/ however I can not get the `bool` operator function to compile the way he has it.

I have vector of event objects. I want to sort the vector based on the event begin time. If the begin times were numbers, this would be easier but they are strings so I had to write functions to convert to `uint64_t`, all of my code up to this sort attempt is working as it should. Here is the code I am trying to get to work:

The bool function:

```
bool EWriter:: operator () ( Event &a,  Event &b){
    return (stringToTime(stringReturnWrap(a.getBeginTime())) < stringToTime(stringReturnWrap(b.getBeginTime()))); 
}
```

This code compiles but I can not figure out how to give it a name, and therefore I cannot reference it in the sort. Also, I would rather overload the `<` operator but I keep getting an error it needs a third argument.

Here is my sort:

```
sort(events->begin(), events->end(), someFunctionName);??
```

Slightly unrelated is that I know I am supposed to use const in the args but I can not call the functions of the Event class if I have them implemented.

Comment: Did you forget to add `const`-ness to your `Event &a` and `Event &b`?

Comment: `Event::getBeginTime()` should be declared `const`. If it's not your code, maybe you could get the author to fix it. If it IS your code, FIX IT! 8v)

Answer (score 2):

By overloading `operator()`, you have made `EWriter` a [*functor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object).

Just pass it an instance of `EWriter`.

If `EWriter` has a default constructor, you can use:

```
sort(events->begin(), events->end(), EWriter());
```

Or pass it an `EWriter` that already exists.

Comment: I was trying to follow an example that was not correct. I should have overloaded the < operator, but the compiler said I needed a third argument to do that and I could not figure out what that would be.

Answer (score 0):

You are overloading the parentheses operator:

```
bool EWriter:: operator () ( Event &a,  Event &b){
    return (stringToTime(stringReturnWrap(a.getBeginTime())) < stringToTime(stringReturnWrap(b.getBeginTime())));
```

}

Try with:

```
bool EWriter:: operator <( Event &a,  Event &b){
    return (stringToTime(stringReturnWrap(a.getBeginTime())) < stringToTime(stringReturnWrap(b.getBeginTime())));
```

}

Comment: I tried that, the compiler kept telling me I needed a third arg

Comment: The answer that got deleted said to make a function basically like what you have only name it compare and remove the operator overload all together. then the vector sort is std::sort(eventVentor.begin(), eventVector.end, compare). That made sense but I got frustrated and wrote a bubble sort that seems to be working. Thanks for the help